# In pursuit of an elegant solution over brute force

Tags: complex-numbers

Here's the problem statement

> Let a,b & c be three real numbers and $w=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$.Compute $(a+bw+cw^2)(a+bw^2+cw)$

Is there any geometric way to do this rather than multiplying it out?

Comment: It is $|a + b w+c w^2|^2  = |(a - \frac{b+c}{2}) + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(b-c)|^2$

Comment: Note that $\overline{a+bw+cw^2}= a+bw^2+cw$.

Comment: Oh I completely overlooked that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: These hints seem to me to be very complicated ways of working out the product: if we remember that $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$ and that $\omega^3=1$ then just multiply it out: the coefficients of $a^2,b^2,c^2$ are clearly $1$, and the coefficient of each cross term $ab,ac,bc$ is clearly $\omega+\omega^2=-1$. Done, and this is not brute force. But the setter asks for a geometric argument, and so far no one has offered one.